# What's wrong with Macro definition in the C code?

Tags: c

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void function(int var)
{
    if(var == TRUE) {
        dosomething();
    }
}
```

During an interview, I was showed the code. However, I think it's right. And I also try this on my computer.

Comment: For me the macro definitions here are correct. The only thing  that could be somewhat "wrong" is not using the definitions in `stdbool.h`.

Comment: What happens when `var` holds the value `2`? This code is kinda lying.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that `if(var == TRUE)` is a bit redundant, `if(var)` would work as well. But that's not in the definition

Comment: BTW, there are plenty of "what's wrong" interview questions that you can "try on your computer" and they will appear to work. The whole point is to glean if you possess the required experience and insight. So don't assume that "working" code is "okay" code.

Comment: Actually the _definitions_ here are perfectly correct. But the _way the `TRUE` macro is used here_ is questionable.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong with the macro definition. However, the `if` condition needs an explanation.

Note the difference between:

```
if (var == TRUE)
```

`1` makes the condition true and every other value makes it false.

and

```
if (var)
```

Every value except `0` makes the condition true. Only `0` makes it false.

Comment: Exactly, if(var) is more natural than using any if (var == TRUE).